# Using python Popen to ssh to instance

Tags: python, windows, ssh

I am currently trying to use Python's Popen command to ssh first to my credential's server then into my wanted instance. I am running into an issue, in Window's Git Bash, with Python's escape character running the ssh command. Below is my command and the warning message I am getting.

```
   ssh_command = "ssh %s -o 'ProxyCommand ssh %s -i %s %s@%s -W %%h:%%p' %s%s -i %s" % (
                verbose_flag, verbose_flag, keyfile, self.user, self.ip_address,
                instance_user, private_ip, keyfile)

subprocess.check_call(ssh_command, shell=True)
```

`Warning: Identity file H:.sshkeyfile not accessible: No such file or directory.`

I have double checked that the file getting passed in, `keyfile`, is indeed `H:\\.ssh\keyfile`. What I don't understand is that if I change `keyfile` to `H:\\\\.ssh\\keyfile`, I still get the same warning message. It seems it doesn't matter how many `\`'s I add, the warning message will always show.

I have been able to figure out that if I pass `H://.ssh/keyfile`, the Unix path style, it works. I am wondering first why this works and if there is a better way to pass the filename to the ssh command.

Comment: windows Git Bash commands must expect MSYS/slashes paths, and "eat" the backslashes. Your workaround is okay. You could use `keyfile.replace(os.sep,"/")`

Comment: Currently my working around is similar ```keyfile.replace(os.path.sep, os.path.altsep)```

Comment: using ssh from Git bash is already a workaround for ssh. You could look at the paramiko module and drop all that crap.

Comment: I think using paramiko I get a similar issue. It can't find my keyfile